# wxPython Program Scan

Tags: python, wxpython

I am trying to get a better understanding of how wxPython 'scans'.

Please see my code below:

```
import os
import wx
from time import sleep

NoFilesToCombine = 0

class PDFFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, title, size=(400,400))
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.Show()

        try:                        #Set values of PDFNoConfirmed to zero on 1st initialisation
            if PDFNoConfimed != 0:
                None
        except UnboundLocalError:     
            PDFNoConfimed = 0   
        try:                        #Set values of PDFNoConfirmed to zero on 1st initialisation
            if PDFNoConfirmedInitially != 0:
                None
        except UnboundLocalError:     
            PDFNoConfirmedInitially = 0   

        while ((PDFNoConfimed == 0) and (PDFNoConfirmedInitially == 0)):
            while PDFNoConfirmedInitially == 0:
                BoxInputNo = wx.NumberEntryDialog(panel, "So You Want To Combine PDF Files?", "How Many?", "Please Enter", 0, 2, 20)
                if BoxInputNo.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK: #NumberEntryDialog Pressed OK
                    NoFilesToCombine = BoxInputNo.GetValue()
                    PDFNoConfirmedInitially = 1
                elif BoxInputNo.ShowModal() == wx.ID_CANCEL:
                    exit()
            print(NoFilesToCombine)
            ConfirmationLabel = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, label="You Have Selected " + str(NoFilesToCombine) + " Files To Combine, Is This Right?", pos=(20, 100))
            ConfirmationBoxConfirm = wx.ToggleButton(panel, label="Confirm", pos=(20, 200))
            ConfirmationBoxCancel = wx.ToggleButton(panel, label="Cancel", pos=(180, 200))
            #if ConfirmationBoxConfirm.GetValue() == 1:
            #    exit()
            if ConfirmationBoxCancel.GetValue() == 1:
                PDFNoConfirmedInitially = 0

app = wx.App()
frame = PDFFrame(None, title="Robs PDF Combiner Application")
app.MainLoop()
```

Now this is a work in progress so it obviously isn't complete.  However what I'm trying to accomplish with the above is:

1. Display a number entry popup.  If user presses 'cancel' exit the application (this works but needs 2 presses for some reason?). If press OK, then:
2. Display the number entered in step 1, with 2 additional buttons.  The 'confirm' doesn't do anything as yet, but the 'cancel' should take you back to step 1. (by resetting the `PDFNoConfirmedInitially` flag).

Now step 2 doesn't work.  When I debug it almost appears as though the `PDFFrame`only gets scanned once.  My presumably false assumption being that this would be continually scanned due to `app.MainLoop()` continually scanning wx.App() which in turn would call the child frame?

Help/ pointers/ deeper understanding always appreciated,

Thanks
Rob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) `ShowModal()` shows dialog window and you use it two times

```
if BoxInputNo.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
```

and

```
elif BoxInputNo.ShowModal() == wx.ID_CANCEL:
```

so it shows your window two times.

And only at second time you check `wx.ID_CANCEL`.

You should run it only once and check its result

```
result = BoxInputNo.ShowModal()

if result == wx.ID_OK:
    pass
elif result == wx.ID_CANCEL:
    self.Close()
    return
```

---

2) You have to assign function to button and this function should reset variable and show dialog window again. But I think `wx.Button` could be better then `wx.ToggleButton`

```
    ConfirmationBoxCancel = wx.Button(panel, label="Cancel", pos=(180, 200))
    ConfirmationBoxCancel.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.on_button_cancel)

def on_button_cancel(self, event):
    #print('event:', event)
    pass
    # reset variable and show dialog window
```

---

Frankly I don't understand some of your variables. Maybe if you use `True/False` instead of `0/1` then they will be more readable. But main problem for me are `while` loops. GUI frameworks (wxPython, tkinter, PyQt, etc) should run only one loop - `Mainloop()`. Any other loop may block `Mainloop()` and GUI will freeze.

I created own version without any `while` loop but I don't know if it resolve all problems

```
import wx

class PDFFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        super().__init__(parent, -1, title, size=(400,400))

        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.Show()

        # show dialog at start 
        if self.show_dialog(self.panel):
            # create StaticLabel and buttons
            self.show_confirmation(self.panel)
        else:
            # close main window and program
            self.Close()


    def show_dialog(self, panel):
        """show dialog window"""

        global no_files_to_combine

        box_input_no = wx.NumberEntryDialog(panel, "So You Want To Combine PDF Files?", "How Many?", "Please Enter", 0, 2, 20)

        result = box_input_no.ShowModal()

        if result == wx.ID_OK: #NumberEntryDialog Pressed OK
            no_files_to_combine = box_input_no.GetValue()
            return True
        elif result == wx.ID_CANCEL:
            print('exit')
            return False


    def show_confirmation(self, panel):
        """create StaticLabel and buttons"""

        self.confirmation_label = wx.StaticText(self.panel, -1, label="You Have Selected {} Files To Combine, Is This Right?".format(no_files_to_combine), pos=(20, 100))

        self.confirmation_box_confirm = wx.Button(self.panel, label="Confirm", pos=(20, 200))
        self.confirmation_box_cancel = wx.Button(self.panel, label="Cancel", pos=(180, 200))
        # assign function
        self.confirmation_box_confirm.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.on_button_confirm)
        self.confirmation_box_cancel.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.on_button_cancel)


    def update_confirmation(self):
        """update existing StaticLabel"""

        self.confirmation_label.SetLabel("You Have Selected {} Files To Combine, Is This Right?".format(no_files_to_combine))


    def on_button_cancel(self, event):
        """run when pressed `Cancel` button"""

        #print('event:', event)

        # without `GetValue()`        
        if self.show_dialog(self.panel):
            # update existing StaticLabel
            self.update_confirmation()
        else:
            # close main window and program
            self.Close()


    def on_button_confirm(self, event):
        """run when pressed `Confirn` button"""

        #print('event:', event)

        # close main window and program
        self.Close()


# --- main --- 

no_files_to_combine = 0

app = wx.App()
frame = PDFFrame(None, title="Robs PDF Combiner Application")
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Thank you ever so much for taking the time to work through my issue and answer so thoroughly.  Been a great help and I much appreciate it